# How to store a value in HashMap (Android)?

Tags: android, hashmap

im worked in soap message, using SAXparser to retrieve the value(from Webservice) stored in ArrayList and the ArrayList working fine, but i want to store in HashMap, because Using key to identify a each name has certain SystemId, Please any one help me

```
Thanks

I tried the code:

    public class SitesList 
    {
    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> systemid = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Map <String,String> map =  new HashMap<String,String>();

    public ArrayList<String>  getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String nameString)   
{
    this.name.add(nameString);

    System.out.println("name  "+ name); 

}

public ArrayList<String>  getSystemId()
{
    return systemid;
}

public void setSystemId(String systemidString)   
{
    this.systemid.add(systemidString);

        System.out.println("systemid  "+systemid);


  }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are getting in storing the value?

Comment: i didnot get total count for arraylist for name

Comment: You question don't seem to be clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: retrieve the value are stored in hashmap from webservice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can store like this way

you arraylist for name

```
private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and HashMap like this way

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>h = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

and you can store your arraylist like this way

```
h.put("name", name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the order of entries, you can do something like this:

```
public class SitesList {
    private final Map <String,String> map =  new HashMap<String,String>();

    public Set<String> getNames() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    public void add(String nameString, String systemidString) {
        map.put(nameString, systemidString);
    }

    public Collection<String> getSystemIds() {
        return map.values(); // may contain duplicates
    }
}
```